# Как заполнить поле Selenium на Python'e

Tags: python, selenium

Сам элемент html

````
<textarea rows="1" placeholder="Написать #чат-экономика" tabindex="1" class="textArea-2Spzkt textArea-2Spzkt scrollbarGhostHairline-1mSOM1 scrollbar-3dvm_9" style="height: auto;"> ```Тут должен быть текст для ввода в поле```</textarea>
````

Класс и тег не находит. По другому я не умею.

Comment: Можно немного конкретики и какие-то примеры вашего кода, а то сейчас вопрос выглядит очень смутно и непонятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кликаешь ПКМ по элементу, нажимаешь скопировать `Xpath`, делаешь `find_element_by_xpath()`, далее у элемента попробуй вызвать метод `send_keys()`, и впиши в него то, что надо написать, возможно перед этим надо на него кликнуть `click()`.

Вот дока: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Comment: Удивительно, все сработало. Благодарю.